# AppSettings value always null net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, appsettings

I am having a problem trying to get values ​​from the json file and binding them to the JwtSettings class using the IOptions <> class, but each time the value is null or 0
Startup class:

```
 public class Startup
{
    private readonly IOptions<JwtSettings> _settings;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IOptions<JwtSettings> settings)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _settings = settings;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public IContainer ApplicationContainer { get; private set; } 

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<JwtSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("JwtSettings"));
        services.AddJwt(_settings);
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        //register commandModules 
        builder.Populate(services);
        builder.RegisterModule(new ContainerModules(Configuration));
        ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();

        return new AutofacServiceProvider(ApplicationContainer);
    }
```

The extensions method when i Use Options:

```
        public static void AddJwt(this IServiceCollection services, IOptions<JwtSettings> setting)
    {
        IConfiguration configuration;
        using (var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
        {
            configuration = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
        }
        services.AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(setting.Value.Key)),
                    ValidIssuer = setting.Value.Issuer,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true
                };
            });
    }
```

On Program class i Add Call ConfigureAppConfiguration when building the Web Host to specify the app's configuration

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);
                config.AddCommandLine(args);
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

The json appsettings looks that:
[image]

Comment: can you show a copy of your appsettings.json file?

Comment: now i add json to post

Answer (score 3):

I kept getting nulls from appsettings.json. In my equivalent to the `JwtSettings` class, my property looked like this:

```
public int QueryLimit { get; }
```

Didn't think I needed the setter but apparently if you don't include it you get some fun side effects! So it works correctly as follows:

```
public int QueryLimit { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor parameter `IOptions<JwtSettings>` is not populated at the time you think it is. When the constructor is called the `ConfigureServices` method has not been executed so the framework does not have anything to inject into the constructor except for the default value of `JwtSettings`.

Even when you call `services.Configure<JwtSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("JwtSettings"));` this does not populate the `IOptions<JwtSettings>` because it has already been injected into the constructor - the framework doesn't update or re-inject the value. This means you have to read the settings yourself within `ConfigureServices` (or your extension method) and you can then use the values. e.g.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<JwtSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("JwtSettings"));

    services.AddJwt(Configuration);

    services
        .AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}


public static void AddJwt(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var settings = configuration.GetSection("JwtSettings").Get<JwtSettings>();

    ....
}
```

Once the `ConfigureServices` method is complete you can inject `IOptions<JwtSettings>` into controllers/services and it will be populated.

I know this isn't as clean as using the `IOptions<JwtSettings>` parameter but you are trying to use the DI system before it has been initialized so you need to read the settings manually at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see if you are reading your configurations from your appsettings.json. Where did you specify that? Something like this:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

 Configuration = builder.Build();
```

If you have more than one appsettings. Like(appsettings.Development.json), Prod, etc.

```
  var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

you need to check the environment variable for your application. Your IConfiguration should take the sections from there

[image]

If you have that deployed on your IIS for example, check here:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This i add on CreateWebHostBuilder in Program class